# Remove the anchor in nav loop based on another field conditional

Tags: conditional, children

I'm using [this solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11443/show-only-children-of-current-page-in-submenu) to output the children within a current structure entry.  Unfortunately I need to take out the anchor on some entries that don't yet have content, but still include the (unlinked) title.

I'm trying the following

```
{% nav page in subnav  %}
  {% if page.id != entry.id %}
  <li>{% if page.pageIntroText|length %}<a href="{{ page.url }}">{%endif%}{{ page.title }}{% if page.pageIntroText|length %}</a>{%endif%}</li>
  {%else%}
  <li class="current-page">{{ page.title }}</li>{%endif%}
{% endnav %}
```

.. but it removes the anchor regardless of whether there is any content in pageIntroText field?

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `{% if page.pageIntroText|length %}` have you tried

`{% if page.pageIntroText is not empty %}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...  it didn't work.  I now have this: 
        {% nav page in subnav  %}
          <li>
            {% if page.pageIntroText is not empty %}
              <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
            {{ page.title }}
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endnav %}

Comment: Bizarre!  I've just tried using a different field for the conditional and it's worked fine???

Comment: What type of input is *pageIntroText*? I assumed it was Plain or Rich Text.

Comment: I'm an idiot! I have two fields, pageIntroText and practiceIntroText, this section is querying practiceIntroText.  Thanks for your help :/